# Fill area Between Two Lines with Only One Intersection

Tags: tikz-pgf, fillbetween

I am trying to fill the area between these two lines that only connect one one end.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berkeley}%{Marburg}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads also tikz
\usepackage{multirow}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}% to avoid the pgfplots warning
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfdeclarelayer{pre main}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale =1.3]
        \draw [step=.25,gray,very thin] (0,0)grid(5,5);
    
    
    \node [right] at (5.1,2.2) {\rotatebox{90}{\scriptsize Sense-Object $S$}};
    \node [below,left] at (2.8,-.3) {\scriptsize Sense-Object $R$};
    
    \node [align=right] at (5.6,4.8) {\scriptsize Origin for\\ \scriptsize Person $1$};
    \node [align=right] at (-.7,.7) {\scriptsize Origin for\\\scriptsize Person $2$};
    
    %initial endowment
    %\node [circle, fill=blue] at (2.5,3){};
    \fill[red] (.5,4.25) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw[red, thick, name path = A] plot [smooth] coordinates {(.5,4.25)(2.5,4.1)(4.75,3.05)};
    \draw[blue, thick, name path = B] plot [smooth] coordinates {(.5,4.25)(2.75,2.75)(5,2.37)};
    \fillbetween[of=A and B];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

I am simply trying to fill the area between the red and blue lines with a partial transparent color. I want the filling to end just at the end of the red line.
[image]

Comment: It should not be an issue, but where do you want your filling to end? On the far right or just at the end of the red line? Or even do you want the end of the red line to be linked to the end of the blue line?

Comment: @SebGlav: Thank you for asking. I want the filling to end just at the end of the red line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fillbetween` can only be used inside `pgfplots` environment, so here you have to add `\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.fillbetween}`. Then, with a bit of cheating (creating a third path, named B and ending at x=4.75) you get this:

[image: fill tikz in between]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{nicefrac}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}% loads also tikz
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}% to avoid the pgfplots warning
    \usetikzlibrary{intersections,pgfplots.fillbetween}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \pgfdeclarelayer{pre main}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale =1.3]
        \draw [step=.25,gray,very thin] (0,0)grid(5,5);
    
    
    \node [right] at (5.1,2.2) {\rotatebox{90}{\scriptsize Sense-Object $S$}};
    \node [below,left] at (2.8,-.3) {\scriptsize Sense-Object $R$};
    
    \node [align=right] at (5.6,4.8) {\scriptsize Origin for\\ \scriptsize Person $1$};
    \node [align=right] at (-.7,.7) {\scriptsize Origin for\\\scriptsize Person $2$};
    
    %initial endowment
    %\node [circle, fill=blue] at (2.5,3){};
    \fill[red] (.5,4.25) circle (1.5pt);
    
    \draw[red, thick, name path = A] plot [smooth] coordinates {(.5,4.25)(2.5,4.1)(4.75,3.05)};
    \draw[blue, thick] plot [smooth] coordinates {(.5,4.25)(2.75,2.75)(5,2.37)};
    \path[name path = B] plot [smooth] coordinates {(.5,4.25)(2.75,2.75)(4.75,2.38)};
    
    
    \tikzfillbetween[of=A and B]{blue, opacity=0.2};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help on this one! Happy New Year!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red, thick] plot[smooth] coordinates {(.5,4.25)(2.5,4.1)(4.75,3.05)};
\draw[blue, thick] plot[smooth] coordinates {(.5,4.25)(2.75,2.75)(5,2.37)};
\clip (0,2) rectangle (4.75,5);
\fill[blue, opacity=0.2] plot[smooth] coordinates {(.5,4.25)(2.5,4.1)(4.75,3.05)} -- plot[smooth] coordinates {(5,2.37)(2.75,2.75)(.5,4.25)} -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Red and blue curve with fill between]